# Why xcode 9 show me a swift 4 warning if I'm programming in swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, xcode9

After update my xcode to 9 it's started to showing me this warning:

> When calling this function in Swift 4 or later, you must pass a '()'
>   tuple; did you mean for the input type to be '()'?

I understand what I should do to solve this warning but I do not understand why I get it because my project is in **SWIFT 3**, no in **SWIFT 4**

Comment: Check at your App targets (build settings), if the Swift compiler language version is set to Swift 3.2

Comment: also, do not confuse a warning with an error. (Yeah, bad on Apple's part, but still - eventually you *will* need to upgrade to Swift 4.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning means exactly what it says - you need to pass a tuple when you call this function in Swift 4. That's useful advice when you are using Swift 3 and want to write code today that doesn't break tomorrow. If you were using Swift 4, you would probably be told that you need to pass a tuple when you call this function (with no mentioning of Swift 4).

Apple helps you fix problems before they become problems.

Comment: Thank you! now I understand, I always try to keep my code free of warnings and I have many of these warnings, it's very annoying, I will have to fix them all :D